# Alternative to Marcus's Number Fields with complete proofs

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I originally learned algebraic number theory from Marcus's Number Fields book and think it is a wonderful book. Unfortunately, almost every proof leaves at least one unproved statement to the reader. Sometimes, I want to go back and quickly review a proof of a theorem without the burden of reinventing proofs. Can anyone suggest some other algebraic number theory books at a similar level to Marcus that genuinely have complete proofs of the theorems?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: [Neukrich](http://barbra-coco.dyndns.org/yuri/Algebraic-Number-Theory.pdf), [Lang](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?req=lang+algebraic&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def), [Hecke](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?req=hecke+algebraic&open=0&res=25&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I have a copy of Neukirch and it is like Marcus until page 65 when he starts treating everything locally which is a totally different way of thinking about the topic. Lang goes local by page 22 and is not similar to Marcus either.  I spent hundreds of hours studying Lang's Algebraic Number Theory in grad school because my advisor told me to, but Lang's clarity is so poor that it was mostly a waste of time.  I'll see if I can find Hecke in the library.

Comment: I personally like Alaca & Williams, *Introductory Algebraic Number Theory*, even though I have yet to read the whole book.

Comment: Robert,  I actually taught a course using Alaca and Williams a few years ago.  It was quite a nice book.  It had a good mix of theory and examples.  I used it for a graduate course but decided it was just a little lower than the level of our students at BYU and so chose Marcus this time because I thought it would be at a more appropriate level.  I'm finding preparation for class a little more time consuming than I had expected.